# I want to know why the output of the program is 3. It is List methods in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
list1 = [6, 8, 5, 6, 1, 2]
print(list1.index(6, 1))
```

OP is: 3

1. list1 is a list in python
2. Here list methods are taking place

But I am confused with the above code

Comment: As opposed to what? Did you read the docs for that method, which explain what the arguments mean?

Comment: @jonrsharpe This is python list method but I am confused with the output Please explain

Comment: Read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations), they already explain it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to print this and you will understand why you got this 3

```
print(list1.index(6))
```

Anyway, here is a summary for what happened. From the code above I can see you have request to look for number six and print it after index 1. However,  if you tried to print

```
print(list1.index(6,0))
```

It will start looking for 6 in the list from index 0 and it will give you 6 at index 0 try to print after index 4 and it will give an error because after index 4 there is no 6 number in the list and you receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: 6 is not in list
```

I hope I was able to answer what in your mind. Also try to check this link for more details.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-index/

All the best in learning python ;)